# Auto start IntelliJ MacOS

Tags: intellij-idea

last week I installed IntelliJ on my Macbook and now I have a Problem with the autostart, I have following question:

How can I disable the autostart from IntelliJ in MacOS when I start my macbook?

I Installed IntelliJ and did no configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Please navigate to Mac's System Settings | General | Login Items. From here, you will be able to add(+) or remove(-) apps which start when you login the Mac.